# How to enable gzip compression in Jetty?

Tags: jetty, gzip, configuration-files, servlet-filters

I would like to know how to enable gzip compression for static files (js, css, html and images) in broadleaf. I have tried the following in ***web.xml*** file of project and I've also got the dependency corresponding to the `org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter` class:

```
<filter>
       <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class> org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
         <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
         <param-value>text/html,text/plain,text/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/css,application/javascript,image/svg+xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
```

The questions I have seeen on Stack Overflow didn't give me the answer, so am I posting a new question. In my project, I have a ***jetty-web.xml*** like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

    <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>

</Configure>
```

When I try to add the *filter mappings* in the *jetty-web.xml* file, I am getting an error that it isn't familiar with the *filter* tag.

Is there anything that I should add/modify in HTML/JS/CSS files?

Answer (score 1):

Use `init-param` in `webdefault.xml`:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>gzip</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

or add the handler to `jetty.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Mixin the GZIP Handler                                          -->
<!-- This applies the GZIP Handler to the entire server              -->
<!-- If a GZIP handler is required for an individual context, then   -->
<!-- use a context XML (see test.xml example in distribution)        -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Call name="insertHandler">
    <Arg>
      <New id="GzipHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler">
        <Set name="minGzipSize"><Property name="jetty.gzip.minGzipSize" deprecated="gzip.minGzipSize" default="2048"/></Set>
        <Set name="checkGzExists"><Property name="jetty.gzip.checkGzExists" deprecated="gzip.checkGzExists" default="false"/></Set>
        <Set name="compressionLevel"><Property name="jetty.gzip.compressionLevel" deprecated="gzip.compressionLevel" default="-1"/></Set>
        <Set name="inflateBufferSize"><Property name="jetty.gzip.inflateBufferSize" default="0"/></Set>
        <Set name="syncFlush"><Property name="jetty.gzip.syncFlush" default="false" /></Set>

        <Set name="excludedAgentPatterns">
          <Array type="String">
            <Item><Property name="jetty.gzip.excludedUserAgent" deprecated="gzip.excludedUserAgent" default=".*MSIE.6\.0.*"/></Item>
          </Array>
        </Set>

        <Set name="includedMethodList"><Property name="jetty.gzip.includedMethodList" default="GET" /></Set>
        <Set name="excludedMethodList"><Property name="jetty.gzip.excludedMethodList" default="" /></Set>

<!--
        <Set name="includedMethods">
          <Array type="String">
            <Item>GET</Item>
          </Array>
        </Set>
        <Set name="includedPaths">
          <Array type="String">
            <Item>/*</Item>
          </Array>
        </Set>
        <Set name="excludedPaths">
          <Array type="String">
            <Item>*.gz</Item>
          </Array>
        </Set>
        <Call name="addIncludedMimeTypes">
          <Arg><Array type="String">
            <Item>some/type</Item>
          </Array></Arg>
        </Call>
        <Call name="addExcludedMimeTypes">
          <Arg><Array type="String">
            <Item>some/type</Item>
          </Array></Arg>
        </Call>
-->

      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

**References**

- [jetty.project/jetty-gzip.xml at master · eclipse/jetty.project](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/jetty-gzip.xml)
- [jetty.project/webdefault.xml at master· eclipse/jetty.project](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-deploy/src/test/resources/etc/webdefault.xml)
- [The document type descriptor for the
  org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration class](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd)
- [Configuring the Jetty Maven Plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html)
- [XmlConfiguration (Jetty :: Project 9.4.3.v20170317 API)](http://www.eclipse.org/external/jetty/stable-9/apidocs///org/eclipse/jetty/xml/XmlConfiguration.html)
- [Issue #1566 · eclipse/jetty.project: ServletContext is not reset/cleared between stop/start](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1566)